# How can I share table report containing 90 users to each user his own data?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I've table report containing 90 users data.
I want to share with each user so he sees only his filtered data.
Currently my only solution is filter each user then share filtered report table one by one
is there any better solution?

Comment: Lookup "Power BI RLS" (Row Level Security)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with Row Level Security in PowerBI:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-rls

Comment: Thank you for guiding me in correct direction. I was able to achieve my goal by using Dynamic RLS using USERPRINCIPALNAME Function.
Link below and 1 YouTube video helped me out.
https://radacad.com/dynamic-row-level-security-with-power-bi-made-simple